# SSH cannot login with root pasword

Tags: ssh, embedded, embedded-linux

I have a buildroot system that I cannot login into with via root.

Root login using `.ssh/authorized_keys` working, but isn't practical since it's a read-only filesystem. Telnet root login also works.

How can I enable password-based login and can I enable logging of `sshd` to get more info?

- **`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:**

  ```ini
  Subsystem  sftp                   = /usr/libexec/sftp-server
  PermitRootLogin                   = yes
  PasswordAuthentication            = yes
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication   = yes
  ```
- **`/etc/passwd`:**

  ```ini
  root:CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh
  daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/false
  bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/false
  sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/false
  sync:x:4:100:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
  mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/spool/mail:/bin/false
  www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/false
  operator:x:37:37:Operator:/var:/bin/false
  test:<hash>/:100:100:user:/home/test:/bin/sh
  nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/home:/bin/false
  sshd:x:1000:1000:SSH drop priv user:/:/bin/false
  ```
- **`/etc/shadow`**

  ```ini
    daemon:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    bin:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    sys:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    sync:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    mail:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    www-data:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    operator:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    nobody:*:10933:0:99999:7:::
    sshd:*:::::::
  ```
- **`ssh -v root@device`**

  ```sh
  OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to device [192.168.10.202] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug1: Authenticating to device:22 as 'root'
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

  debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VY8wYy/5GDoAl39tVLWHtJcUaDFUfLR1/3hiTBbv+ww
          The authenticity of host 'device (192.168.10.202)' can not be established.
          ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:VY8wYy/5GDoAl39tVLWHtJcUaDFUfLR1/3hiTBbv+ww.
          Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
          Warning: Permanently added 'device,192.168.10.202' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:+pbphA33IlRNVBroM+DLokCIZII2eSzo095QDT16gNI /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive

  debug1: Next authentication method: password
          root@device password:

  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
          Permission denied, please try again.
  ```

  - **`/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd`**

  ```ini
  debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 244
  debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 244
  debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:54 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
  debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:110 setting UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox     
  debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:126 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
  debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
  debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtvkz2AWVxGD065gePcrwgk
  debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX21Yy3P+jgZdxlnWlPCQ8
  debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtCs3ZIhpDfB0bBPukcIdsc
  debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXzJwAiPEnQSXzrTk
  debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
  debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
  debug3: oom_adjust_setup
  debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
  Server listening on :: port 22.
  debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
  Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
  debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
  debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 244
  debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
  debug3: send_rexec_state: done
  debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
  debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
  Connection from 192.168.10.100 port 64175 on 192.168.10.202 port 22
  debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
  debug2: Network child is on pid 25121
  debug3: preauth child monitor started
  debug3: privsep user:group 1000:1000 [preauth]
  debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1000/1000 [preauth]
  debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
  debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
  debug1: ssh_sandbox_child: prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP): Invalid argument [preauth]
  debug3: list_hostkey_types: ssh-dss key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms [preauth]
  debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
  debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
  debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
  debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
  debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
  debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
  debug3: mm_answer_sign
  debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x7868dac8(99)
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
  debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
  debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
  debug1: KEX done [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
  debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
  debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 244
  debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 2 sp_expire -1 days left -3
  debug3: account expiration disabled
  debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
  debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
  debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for root [preauth]
  debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
  debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
  debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
  debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
  debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
  debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7868d858
  debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
  debug1: trying public key file /home/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
  debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
  debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
  Failed publickey for root from 192.168.10.100 port 64175 ssh2: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwXzMcggx2QWBxvEEdpZR71Yo
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7868d858 is not allowed
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
  debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
  debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
  debug1: auth2_challenge: user=root devs= [preauth]
  debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
  debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 3 failures 2 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
  debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
  debug3: auth_shadow_pwexpired: today 2 sp_lstchg 10933 sp_max 99999
  debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
  Failed password for root from 192.168.10.100 port 64175 ssh2
  debug1: Unable to open the btmp file /var/log/btmp: No such file or directory
  debug3: mm_auth_password: user not authenticated [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  ```

Comment: Won't the password hash have to be in the shadow file and not in the password one? Try adding `root:CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ:10933:0:99999:7:::` to `/etc/shadow`

Comment: @kubanczyk I don't have /etc/pam.d (probably because it's buildroot Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Remove root's plain-text password from `/etc/passwd` and add an encrypted one in the `/etc/shadow` file

First edit the `/etc/passwd` file from:

```
root:CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh
```

To:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

Then create an encrypted password using `openssl` command:

```
admin@ubuntu:~$ openssl passwd -1 CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ
$1$A20/AqQt$zBfgwEGWNRLQsSk3bYV6V.
```

In this case, the plain-text password is `CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ` and the encrypted version is `$1$A20/AqQt$zBfgwEGWNRLQsSk3bYV6V.`

Then add entries to `/etc/shadow` file:

```
root:$1$A20/AqQt$zBfgwEGWNRLQsSk3bYV6V.:18550:0:99999:7:::
```

From now on, you will be able to SSH and login as root with a password of `CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ` and home directory of `/root`

Comment: @ Bruce Malaudzi
Still fails:

`debug3: auth_shadow_pwexpired: today 18554 sp_lstchg 10 sp_max 999999

debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0

debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13

Failed password for root from 192.168.10.100 port 53936 ssh2`

Comment: To fix this, in the /etc/shadow file, change  17624 to 18550 (see the updated answer). This will restore password expiry dates